# Embedding SSRS Report Viewer in a webpage

Tags: html, sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I want to create in my website a navigation for SSRS. I will have left panel with all the reports I have and on the right I will have a div with the report the user selected. can I embedded the SSRS report viewer in an HTML div?

The report viewer you see when going to:

```
http://<server>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2f<path>%2f<ReportName>&rs:Command=Render
```

Also, can I pass username in the URL? I tried to user

```
http://<server>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2f<path>%2f<ReportName>&rs:Command=Render&UserId='username'
```

and I get error:

```
An attempt was made to set a report parameter 'UserId' that is not defined in this report. (rsUnknownReportParameter)
```

Thanks

## **More Info:**

I am using `DataExtensions` and the userid gives me the database I need to connect to. In `winforms` I can use the `Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DataSourceCredentials` object to specify the DB, but in `WebForm` I can't use DataSourceCredentials (readonly)

Any ideas?

Comment: What tool are you using to create this Website? Visual Studio? Is UserId not gettting populated? Are you using Windows Authentication? Need more information to help you with your issue.

Comment: Right now we have VB project for the reports and it works with the entire system. I want to create a standalone aspx page to show the reports. I want to be able to pass userid in the code and show the report

Comment: There is a built in Global called UserId which is the user requesting the report use that for item #2

Comment: You can't pass in the UserId field - it's a built in and not used for authentication

Answer (score 1):

(rsUnknownReportParameter) means you are trying to set a report parameter that does not exist. I would suggest looking at your report again and making sure its spelled correctly in both SSRS and on your URL.

For your first question the answer is yes, you could create different pages for your reports on your site and use the report viewer control to reference the server reports on those pages. Then on your menu change the div iframe to whatever report you wanted to navigate to. Throw Something like this in your menu button Report

That will change the src of a iframe with the id IframeID. Theres a few different ways to accomplish your question of adding SSRS reports to a web app. This is just my go to method.

Click [here for the error msg](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/support/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=SQL+Server+Reporting+Services&ProdVer=8.00&EvtID=rsUnknownReportParameter&EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.ErrorStrings.resources&LCID=1033)